# Uma Macro para executar todos os Módulos?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Tenho vários módulos e dentro desses módulos tenho várias sub-rotinas com algumas funções em folhas separadas. Pretendo executar as macros separadamente! Ou seja, iniciar a próxima sub rotina após finalização da sub-rotina anterior.

EXEMPLO DE UM DOS MÓDULOS COM VÁRIAS ROTINAS:

```
Sub um()
'código [...]
dois
End sub

Sub dois()
'código [...]
tres
End sub

Sub tres()
'código [...]
End sub
```

Como criar um módulo que execute todas as macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos os *módulos, funções e subs* são interligados no Excel, poderia ter cada *sub* independente e ter uma outra função para rodar tudo em sequência, assim:

```
Sub um()
'código [...]
End Sub

Sub dois()
'código [...]
End Sub

Sub tres()
'código [...]
End Sub
```

E a que roda na sequência:

```
Sub RodaTudo()

 ' Chama a Sub UM
 um

 ' Chama a Sub DOIS
 dois

 ' Chama a Sub tres
 tres

End Sub
```

Algo que utilizo muito são as *funções* ao invés de *sub* existem algumas diferenças, mas basicamente duas:

1. As funções não aparecem para o usuário quando na planilha tenta rodar uma macro, por exemplo, estando na planilha o usuário pode pressionar *Alt+F8* para mostrar as macros e tentar rodar alguma, se for função ao invés de sub, não estará lá.
2. As funções podem receber e retornar valores e poderia ser melhor explorado no código, assim:

   ```
   Function um(ByVal TESTE As String) As Boolean
    'código [...]
    If TESTE = "Rodar Próxima" Then
      um = True
    End If
   End Function


   Function um(ByVal TESTE As String) As Boolean
    'código [...]
    If TESTE = "Rodar Próxima" Then
      um = True
    End If
   End Function

   Function DOIS(ByVal RODADOIS As Boolean) As Boolean
    'código [...]
    If RODADOIS Then
      DOIS = True
    End If
   End Function

   Function tres(ByVal DOIS As Boolean) As String
    'código [...]
    If DOIS Then
      tres = "Rodou tudo!"
    End If
   End Function
   ```

E uma Sub para chamar pela planilha, validando o resultado de cada função:

```
Sub RodaTudo()

  ' Aqui chamará a Função UM, depois a DOIS (caso o resultado seja true) e depois a TRES (caso o resultado da DOIS seja true)
  tres (DOIS(um("Rodar Próxima")))

  ' Ou pode-se fazer testes
  If um("Rodar Próxima") Then ' Se verdadeiro rodar abaixo
    dois(true)
  End If        

End Sub
```

P.S.: *Subs* podem somente receber valores, mas não retornam valores diretamente.